# Problema com tipos em parâmetro de função

Tags: php, string, parâmetros

Ao executar o seguinte código:

```
function foo(string $text) {
    echo $text;
}
foo('bar');
```

Obtenho o seguinte erro:

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to foo() must be an instance of string, string given, called in /home/...

Fiquei intrigado pois nunca tinha feito antes com `Strings`, sempre fiz com `Array`, e deu certo.

**Pergunta**
O erro ocorreu porque o método pedia uma instância de `string`, mas `'bar'` não é uma instância de `string`? Se `'bar'` não é uma instância de `string`, qual parâmetro eu devo colocar para que esta função seja executada corretamente?

Creio eu que este erro deveria ser melhor explicado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](http://pt1.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php):

> Type hints **can not be** used with scalar types such as int or **string**. Resources and Traits are not allowed either.

De forma simples, não podes forçar o parâmetro para o tipo `string` por ser um tipo escalar que não é suportado.

---

**Nota:** Esta informação não consta na [versão Portuguesa do manual](http://pt1.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.typehinting.php), não sei porque visto ser importante, mas diz que:

> ...Funções podem forçar que os parâmetros sejam objetos ... ou array...

Que de certa forma também nos diz que `string` não está incluído.

---

#### Edição:

Para verificares se é uma `string` conforme o exemplo que deste, só mesmo *à moda antiga*:

```php
function foo($text) {
    if (is_string($text))
        echo $text;
    else
        echo "Aqui só strings amigo!";
}
```

Ou como visto no tópico cujo [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103480/really-php-argument-1-passed-to-my-function-must-be-an-instance-of-string-s) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> foi colocado nos comentários:

```php
function foo($text) {
    if (!is_string($text)) {
        trigger_error('No, you fool!');
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

<sup>Link foi uma cortesia do @LuizVieira</sup>

Comment: Pergunta do SO(en) que atesta esta resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103480/really-php-argument-1-passed-to-my-function-must-be-an-instance-of-string-s (há, inclusive, uma sugestão de classe string para permitir o type-hint desse jeito - creio que a antepenúltima resposta)

Comment: Eu realmente achei que PHP tinha uma classe string.

Comment: Implementar uma classe `String` no PHP é muito overhead. Como não existe suporte a sobrecarga de operadores, você dependerá de métodos para fazer coisas simples, como concatenação, etc.